# How to see current context when debugging template errors?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am getting a template error during rendering, which I think would be easy to fix if I could just see what's in the context that is passed into the template that is being rendered.  Django's debug error page provides a lot of information, but I'm not seeing my context anywhere.  Am I missing something?  Also, I am using Django-debug-toolbar, but that only seems to come up if the page successfully renders.  Not being able to see the contents of the context that is passed to the template makes debugging some types of template errors hard! What do I need to do to be able to see it in this scenario?   (Note that I'm not asking for a fix to my specific error, which is why I'm not providing more information about it).

Comment: I think you need to walk up the stracktrace (in the django debug page) to actually see your context variables. I don't understand your problem exactly. If I have a template error I can inspect my context somewhere in the traceback.

Comment: Torsten, I've since realized that the best place to do this is to set a breakpoint in the view to look at the context (get_context_data for CBV's).  I'd be happy to accept your comment as an answer to my question.

Comment: Hm, yes, setting a "breakpoint" in django can sometimes mean just inserting a non-defined variable at the point you want to inspect ^^. The last entry in the traceback is usually the one for this variable. It will give you all context details in the traceback of the debug page. I add the previous and this comment as an answer. Feel free to whatever you like with it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments:

I think you need to walk up the stacktrace (in the django debug page) to actually see your context variables. I don't understand your problem exactly. If I have a template error I can inspect my context somewhere in the traceback.

Yes, setting a "breakpoint" in django can sometimes mean just inserting a non-defined variable at the point you want to inspect. The last entry in the traceback is usually the one for this variable. It will give you all context details in the traceback of the debug page.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with the [Django Debug Toolbar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar/0.8.4). it will give you a popup tab on the right hand side of your screen that you can use to inspect various things about the current page's request. Things like SQL statements, versions, logging, and all the templates that were used to render the page, and the context available to each of them.

Comment: I agree that django debug toolbar is great and I noted in my question that i'm using it, but it doesn't solve my problem.  Unfortunately the toolbar only renders if there aren't any errors in rendering the page, so if you have a template rendering error because of something in your context it seems there is no way to inspect that context.  I fixed my bug, but I'm sure this will bug me again :)

Comment: Clicking through from the PyPi page to the package's home page (http://rob.cogit8.org/django-debug-toolbar/) leads to a 'page not found' (404) response; I suspect that this package is no longer actively maintained.